# toggling workspaces

Tags: unity, workspaces

I use workspaces a lot in ubuntu, in situations like when I don't want to close apps but search some files in my desktop. And one convienient way is to enable them with hotcorners, since they're quite nearby and requires just moving your mouse.

However, this can be annoying as sometimes your mouse just hovers over THAT hotcorner which is enable for the workspace. So, the behaviour that WOULD be MORE CONVIENIENT is that the hotcorner be active when i SHIFT+HOVER my mouse over THAT hotcorner which is enable for the workspaces. Can I toggle this behaviour in ubuntu?

**I'm using Ubuntu 16.04LTS**

Comment: I cannot check, but install compiz-config-settings: there might be a possibility there to configure hotcorners with "shift". If you do not find it there, it will not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to use the keyboard to help you change workspaces.

A) How about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RightArrow</kbd>?

For my keyboard, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the right of the spacebar make it easy to hit <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> or <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> with my ring finger, so I can do it one-handed.

B) Configure the workspace toggling with a keyboard shortcut, which can be configured via the settings->keyboard and shortcut.

C) Acquire a keyboard with additional programmable keys, which have gotten [reasonable in price](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NNQG0N4).

Comment: that's cool but, you gotta use both hands , I am looking for a way to use only one hand because lifting your hand is a bit of pain.

Comment: um.... we'd normally use the mouse with the right, so, we'd have to leave the mouse in that case as well

Comment: Sorry, I am mouse-bidextrous and have one on each side, depending on what I am doing. See new edits, above.

Comment: thanks for all the help though, though, my rep doesn't allow upvotes

Comment: That's AOK! Thank you for your contribution!